# Cannot programmatically click <a> tag in Greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm trying to get Greasemonkey in Firefox to click this anchor which doesn't have an `href` attribute:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
   ng-class="{'disabled': programsTabSubmitInProgress}"
   ng-click="handleAddProgramClick()">
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
  <span>Add Program</span>
</a>
```

I already tried this line of code, but it won't work:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Final Test
// @description Final test results
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
// @include     https://qs-hub.qs.com/#/profiles/topuniversities/programs*
// ==/UserScript==
setTimeout(function () {
  document.querySelector('.btn.btn-primary.pull-right').click();
}, 5000);
```

Does anyone have the right solution to click this anchor?

Comment: Is that line of code everything in your Greasemonkey script? You should probably wait until the page loads. What are the full contents of the script file?

Comment: I updated the code! I use a timer, so the page can load first.

Comment: What's the jquery for?

Comment: can you console.log() that your `document.querySelector('.btn.btn-primary.pull-right')` is actually finding the element?

Comment: I used a similar script for Tweet deletions, I got the click code working with the jquery require.

Comment: Ah, cargo cult coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should work fine. You do need to ensure that you click the *right* element:

```
console.log(document.querySelector('.btn.btn-primary.pull-right'));
```

As per the comments, you actually want to click the fifth such element. That'd be:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.btn.btn-primary.pull-right').item(4).click();
```

[`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) of which we [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) the fifth [`item`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/item).

You are not using jQuery by the way, so there is no need to require that in your script.

Instead of having the timeout, consider waiting for the page to [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load):

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.btn.btn-primary.pull-right').item(4).click();
}, false);
```